# ValueError while migrating a model in DJango

Tags: python, django, migration

I am trying to create a simple model in Django. The expected fields are some text and owner's user id. However, this is what happens when I execute manage.py migrate (makemigrations worked without an error). I would appreciate any clues to this!

```
Running migrations:
  Applying manage_remittance.0001_initial... OK
  Applying manage_remittance.0002_remittance_owner...Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'default'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'default'.
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Remittance(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remittance_text = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.remittance_text
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Remittance

admin.site.register(Remittance)
```

0002_remittance_owner.py (I have no idea why this was around as I migrated back to version zero and then did makemigrations with the models.py as shown above):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('manage_remittance', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='remittance',
            name='owner',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default='default', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please share the `0002_remittance_owner` migration file. It looks like you have set a default there that makes no sense.

Comment: `
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('manage_remittance', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='remittance',
            name='owner',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default='default', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
    ]
`

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: Did you provide any default value on running makemigrations?

Comment: No, I did not. I just ran `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrations`. The database should be empty at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
field=models.ForeignKey(default='default', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

owner field is ForeignKey with type int() base on id in user table.

You set **default='default'** and it raised ValueError

In Python, If you try to convert any string value not formatted as an integer, this error is raised.

this error message tells us there is an invalid literal for an integer in base 10. This means the value we have passed through an int() method cannot be converted.
'default' can not be converted to an int value for ForeignKey.
delete it or give it a correct value in type integer

Comment: Thanks! The advice worked. I edited the migrations file 0002_remittance_owner.py directly, though. Is that a proper way how to handle the problem?

Comment: Yes .. if you have a default value for ForeignKey set the default value in model class like this:

`owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)`

and you can set `null=True` if owner field sometime hasn’t user related

`owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`

Comment: Thanks again for the help!